# mysql order varchar field as integer

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a varchar field in my table and I want to sort it. But I need to handle this field as integer.  Meaning if sort as text the order is "19,2,20" but I want to get the right order "2,19,20".

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 66):

I somehow didn't manage to run the query with `CAST`. I was always getting `Error Code: 1064 near "DECIMAL"` (or other numeric type that I chose). So, I found another way to sort `varchar` as numbers:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY ABS(mycol)
```

A bit simpler and works in my case.

Answer (score 29):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        CAST(mycol AS DECIMAL)
```

Comment: @Quassnoi: Just wondering, but is CASTing more efficient than ORDER BY mycol+0

Comment: `@dnagirl`: `DECIMAL` will silently truncate everything beyond the `[0-9]` range, `mycol + 0` (which implies `CAST AS DOUBLE`) will issue a warning. As for performance, I think they're identical.

Comment: Abhi Beckert - Can't have a space between CAST and the opening bracket

Answer (score 16):

Here is the solution

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY ABS(MyCol);
```

Answer (score 8):

All other answers use `ABS`, which converts the values into absolute (positive) values, assuming that the integers are positive. A better solution would be to use `* 1`:

`SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY mycol * 1`

This to prevent casting negative numbers into positive ones. Inspired by: [mysql sort string number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417381/mysql-sort-string-number)

Answer (score 5):

You can `ABS()` for this purpose. ABS() is a mathematical function that returns the `absolute (positive) value of the specified expression`. So query will be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY ABS(MyCol);
```

Answer (score 4):

You Can Order varchar field using this code according to your required

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY ABS(mycol)
```