# MySQL sort varchar column numeric, numbers first

Tags: mysql

I've got a varchar column that I want to sort numeric, which works great when using this trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5418033/1005334 (in short: `...ORDER BY Result * 1`).

However, the table concerned contains results. So something like this occurs:

```
Result
------
DNS
DNF
1
2
3
```

The numbers are correctly ordered, but the `DNF` comes above the numbers when sorting like this. What I'd like is to have the numeric sort, but with non-numbers sorted alphabetically **below** the numbers. Like so:

```
Result
------
1
2
3
DNF
DNS
```

In what way can I modify the query (preferably only the `ORDER BY` clause) to get this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use LPAD

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad

```
LPAD(yourField, 20, '0');
```

this will manage correct order for "varchar numeric fields" (10 will be after 2) and put strings at the end.

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/779b4/5)

The second argument (20) is quite arbitrary. It should be equivalent to (or bigger then) the length of the longest string in your field.

Comment: Clean function which seems to work, but I don't get how it does

Comment: @JohnWoo I made a mistake in the arguments order. Corrected. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78de4/3

Comment: @RobinCastlin well, it's just add third argument('0') at the left of a string, x times (where x = second argument (20) - length of string). So if second argument is '3', 1 becomes '001' and '100' becomes '100' Then it's just a "string sort'

Comment: Looks good, but result gets odd when I add more numbers: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66c54/1. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @kasimir as pointed, I made a mistake in the argument order, if you take the actual answer, it will work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66c54/2

Comment: Just read the comments, seems it does fine now: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66c54/2. Let me test a bit more in my own setup.

Comment: A question: why is the `'0'` quoted and the `20` not?

Comment: @kasimir : '0' is the character added at the left. 20 is the length of the resulting string. Look at the doc (link given in answer) for a more complete explanation (BTW, you could remove quotes on '0' in this case, but it makes things clearer)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *, (Result REGEXP '^[0-9]+$') AS is_numeric
FROM table_name
ORDER BY is_numeric DESC, 
    CASE WHEN is_numeric THEN (Result + 0) ELSE Result END ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using **[MySQL's REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)**. Try this one,

```
SELECT *
FROM tablea
ORDER BY  IF(`Result` REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$', 0, 1) ASC,
          `Result` ASC
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bea89/1)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Please change your ORDER BY Clause with this:

```
  ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN Result REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN Result*1 else 999999 END,
       Result
```

This will order the numeric values first then the rest

Comment: @kasimir:I have ipdated my answer  Plz check now

Comment: It works. But I think the `LPAD` solution is a bit more elegant (shorter).

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY CAST(`Result` AS SIGNED) DESC
```

this should work.

Comment: I had tried this one. This gives me reverse order: `3, 2, 1, DNF, DNS`, I'm after `1, 2, 3, DNF, DNS`.