# php mysql order by numbers from right of title

Tags: php, mysqli

I need order by Numbers from end of title but need as UNSIGNED result, i try to get last 5 digit from title table and sort but not giving natural result

title table

```
title1 (2015)
something (1999)
title1 (1994
title1 (2014)
```

My code

```
 ORDER BY RIGHT(title,5) DESC
```

Result is

```
something (1999)
title1 (1994)
title1 (2014)
title1 (2015)
```

How can i Order like this:

```
title1 (2015)
title1 (2014)
something (1999)
title1 (1994)
```

Now this code order like 1,10,101,2,20,201 but i need like this 1,2,10,20,101,201

Comment: `ORDER BY RIGHT(title,5) ASC` ...

Comment: Now this code order like it order 1,10,101,2,20,201 like this i need like this 1,2,10,20,101,201

Comment: You should store years in separate column like `title | year`, data: `title1 | 1994`, `something | 1999`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try like this. See a [DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1bee3/9)

```
select col1 from table1
order by replace(right(col1,5), ')','') desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you substring, it converts the data to text.

You need to convert it back to number ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417381/mysql-sort-string-number)):

```
order by substring(title,-5,4)*1 desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need ORDER BY **ASC** and not DESC.

```
ORDER BY RIGHT(title,5) ASC
```

Learn more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp).

Comment: Now this code order like it order 1,10,101,2,20,201 like this i need like this 1,2,10,20,101,201

Comment: You have only one column in your table? I think for output what you like you need alter your table, and add another column.

Comment: Any other idea using ORDER BY RIGHT??

Comment: Is a problem in your program do another column? I think is the best easier way to output what you like. Create another column, example date, and order by date.

Comment: it is not a date it is year comes with title not auto increment