# Sorting varchar numerically when also sorting by other fields

Tags: mysql, sorting, casting

I need to sort a query's results by a `varchar` that may contain numbers, but also sort by other fields beforehand.

Say my table looks like:

```
+------------------------+-----------------+
| AnotherField           | VarCharWithNums |
+------------------------+-----------------|
| Same Data in Every Row | Numbers 5-10    |
| Same Data in Every Row | Numbers 10-13   |
| Same Data in Every Row | Numbers 13-15   |
+------------------------+-----------------|
```

This query:

```
SELECT VarCharWithNums, AnotherField
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY CAST(VarCharWithNums AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

Gives me this:

```
+------------------------+-----------------+
| AnotherField           | VarCharWithNums |
+------------------------+-----------------|
| Same Data in Every Row | Numbers 5-10    |
| Same Data in Every Row | Numbers 10-13   |
| Same Data in Every Row | Numbers 13-15   |
+------------------------+-----------------|
```

This query:

```
SELECT VarCharWithNums, AnotherField
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY AnotherField ASC, CAST(VarCharWithNums AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

Gives me this:

```
+------------------------+-----------------+
| AnotherField           | VarCharWithNums |
+------------------------+-----------------|
| Same Data in Every Row | Numbers 10-13   |
| Same Data in Every Row | Numbers 5-10    |
| Same Data in Every Row | Numbers 13-15   |
+------------------------+-----------------|
```

It doesn't matter what priority I give the fields in the `ORDER BY` clause, it never sorts `VarCharWithNums` correctly when I order it alongside other fields.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417381/mysql-sort-string-number

Comment: You probably will need to parse out that field to get only one number and use that for sorting (or two, depending one how you want the ranges to sort)

Comment: If the same data is in every row of `AnotherField`, why would you want to sort on it?  Or is that just part of the contrived example?  I have no problems when I set up a test case and try it.

Comment: Look here, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686849/sorting-varchar-field-numerically-in-mysql?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned it in your last paragraph, but truly the only error in what you've shown is that, to get the sort you described, `CAST(VarCharWithNums AS UNSIGNED) ASC` needs to be the *first* thing in the `ORDER BY` clause.  It should work, and it works when I create a contrived example on my machine.