# How to order string values like same as integers in mysql

Tags: mysql

[image]

Please check the above results output. As you can see after `DT - 10` it displays `DT - 100`. But I need to display `DT - 12` instead of `DT - 100`. I tried this in two ways, but the results are same.

#### 1st try

```
SELECT *
FROM fas_details
WHERE equipment_no LIKE 'DT%'
ORDER BY CAST(equipment_no AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```

#### 2nd try

```
SELECT *
FROM fas_details
WHERE equipment_no LIKE 'DT%'
ORDER BY equipment_no * 1 ASC, equipment_no ASC
```

Already checked following questions,

- [mysql sort string number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417381/mysql-sort-string-number)
- [Cast from VARCHAR to INT - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126991/cast-from-varchar-to-int-mysql)

Comment: Would `equipment_no` be always in `DT - *` format?

Comment: Yes it is @AJ. It always in the same format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`equipment_no` is a string and it is sorted as such.
You must extract the integer part after the dash and (implicitly) convert it to an integer and then sort:

```
SELECT *
FROM fas_details
WHERE equipment_no LIKE 'DT%'
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(equipment_no, '-', -1) + 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your time to add this answer and it works.

Answer (score 2):

> Would equipment_no be always in DT - * format?
>
> Yes it is @AJ. It always in the same format.

The numbers in the `equipment_no` will be treated as a string and sorted on such basis. You have to extract these numbers. You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) for this purpose and then cast the result as Integer to sort it.

```
SELECT *
FROM fas_details
WHERE equipment_no LIKE 'DT%'
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(equipment_no, '-', -1) AS UNSIGNED) ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` here but we also must cast the output to an integer before sorting:

```
SELECT *
FROM fas_details
WHERE equipment_no LIKE 'DT%'
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(equipment_no, ' - ', -1) AS UNSIGNED);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time to add this answer and it works.

Comment: I also tried using `Trim` but it doesn't seem necessary.

Answer (score 0):

When sorting on a piece of the 'equipment_no', you also need to notice the alphanumeric part before the number.

When i.e. having values like 'ET - 0' en 'ET - 9' , than 'ET - 9', you do not want an output like:

```
| ET - 0       |
| DT - 01      |
| DT - 02      |
| DT - 03      |
| DT - 04      |
| ET - 9       |
| DT - 10      |
```

This will sort more correct:

```
select * from equipment 
order by 
  substring_index(equipment_no,'-',1), 
  cast(trim(substring_index(equipment_no,'-',-1)) as unsigned);
```

output:

```
| DT - 100     |
| DT - 101     |
| DT - 102     |
| ET - 0       |
| ET - 9       |
```

Last remark, sorting like this will be slow when there are 'a lot of' records because every record (in the selection) has to be fetched to get the sort order!

Comment: Thanks for your time to add this answer and it works.