# PHP / Mysql does not sort correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database and the following php code:

```php
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM database ORDER BY Score DESC');
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   printf ("%s;%s\n", $row["Name"], $row["Score"]);
}
```

The database has rows Name as string and Score also as a string.

The Problem is the Score is not sorted correctly. Why?

Comment: Please remember that we cannot see your screen. You need to include in the question every relevant detail. The `ORDER BY` clause is not generally broken.

Comment: Please show us some "wrong" output :)

Comment: My one guess is that you have numeric strings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5418033/231316

Answer (score 0):

change score column type to int